# How to check the properties of undefined or better bypass it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

First of all, I know I can check undefined by `myVar === 'undefined'`. Now the case is, I'm doing some data fetching from db, sometimes I get a null or undefined data and properties, especially if it's a model with association. For example

```
const result = await Model.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: AnotherModel
    }
  ],
});
```

This will result in an array of object that has property called AnotherModels. Now my question is if AnotherModel is null, how can I check AnotherModel.name (for example) since null.name will throw an error. Should I check AnotherModel and then AnotherModel.name, or is there any easier method to do this.

Comment: `AnotherModel?.name`

Comment: @Lain it's working for null, but not for undefined. But it's new thing for me, thank you so much.

Comment: You could default `AnotherModel` to `null` or use the classical way `AnotherModel ? AnotherModel.name : ''`.

Comment: Now how about if the name is undefined too? It'll gone bad pretty fast like `AnotherModel ? AnotherModel.name ? AnotherModel.name : ''`;, it's not good looking IMO.

Comment: @Lain anyway, if there is no one can answer the undefined case, you may post your comment as answer, I'll accept it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Randi Pratama: Well, I wonder.. if `AnotherModel` is `null` or `undefined`, why are you still adding/processing it? Would it not be more simple to skip it? If `AnotherModel` is **falsy** it can not have properties anyway.

Comment: @Lain since findAll Model that associated with AnotherModel will not always return **falsy**. The associations is messed up, I know, but in my defense it was in testing phase, we split the work to three people, and when inserting or deleting data to the database we don't wipe the database. Well, I just hope it goes well in production phase.